# Swagger UI - customize Models section layout

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui, springfox

I'd like to make some customizations in models layouts, or at least add some comments.

Here is how it looks like by default:

[image]

I use java springfox for swagger UI.
Here is my Swagger config:

[image]

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you are looking for `@ApiModelProperty`. You can annotate each attribute with it and include `value` parameter as the description. Additional details at https://www.baeldung.com/swagger-apiparam-vs-apimodelproperty.

```java
@ApiModelProperty(value = "Your description")
int fromLocation;
```